# HTML & CSS Help position image corner

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble positioning a corner image on to of an image. The span which have an little background image should be in the top left corner on top of the image.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="wrapkon">
<span style="width: 4px; height: 30px;display:block;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px; background-color:#000;background: url(../images/konboxleft.png) no-repeat;"></span>
    <a target="_blank" href="/link/11"><img style="width:125px; height:125px;" src="image.jpg" alt="21883"></a>
div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/jdmiller82/F8ZPG/

You need to set a position relative to your #wrapkon.

also, top and left values should not be in px.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `position: absolute;`, you need `position: relative;` on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your `<div id="wrapkon">` a `position: relative` style.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure wrapkon has position: relative on itself, or the span which you have absolutely positioned will not appear inside it. See this: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/